# Clicking element once with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `one()` method to trigger an action once like so:

```
$("#tabs .nav li a").one("click", function(){ 
       //do something
});
```

This works once for each link. I want it to work once and ONCE ONLY for all the links within the `.nav li` For instance, If I click on .nav li a, I expect the action to trigger. If I click a different link, I no longer want the function to fire.

How would you suggest going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the original event with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) then use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove it:

```
$("#tabs .nav li a").on("click.once", function(){ 
    // do something
    $("#tabs .nav li a").off("click.once");
});
```

This also uses a custom [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) to avoid accidentally removing other `click` events from the elements.

Comment: +1 for namespacing.  Another option would be to pass the function to `off` to only unbind that exact handler.

Comment: Never knew about namespacing, this makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for this

```
$("#tabs .nav li a").on("click", function(){ 
    //do something
    $("#tabs .nav li a").off('click');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use event delegation and bind it to the parent, just like `.on()`:

```
$('#tabs').one('click', '.nav li a', function() {
    // ...
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDfFu/**

Comment: Nice! Though this could potentially be a problem: *"[...] the handler is removed after the first time the event occurs at the delegated element, **whether the selector matched anything or not**."* http://api.jquery.com/one/. Also it wouldn't give the desired result if there are multiple `#tabs .nav` elements.

Comment: @FelixKling: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it saying that if the `click` event is triggered on the parent element, the handler is unbound even if the clicked element doesn't match the selector? If so, I can't seem to get that to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/hDfFu/1/

Comment: Mmmh, interesting. I haven't tested it so I just expected the documentation to be up-to-date. The information seems to be incorrect then, though my second remark (I edited the comment) is still valid. But if the matching is not a problem anymore, you can bind the handler to the body.

Comment: That is a very odd statement in the docs.  What it seems to be saying doesn't even happen using 1.7.0  http://jsfiddle.net/hDfFu/2/  I'm really not sure what that's trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind` or `off` to remove event handlers, like this:

```
$("#tabs .nav li a").on("click.myIdentifier", function(){ 
    //do something

    // unbind event from other elements:
    $("#tabs .nav li a").off('click.myIdentifier');
});
```

Note the added `.myIndentifier` here, which you should always use when removing events you've attached to ensure you're removing only the events you want to; ie. not events which are added by a 3rd party plugin which you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
$("#tabs .nav li a").unbind('click');
```

at the end of the function.